# Load data to a list fragment tab on the creation of the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am absolutely in love with these new components Android is introducing. So, I am building a standard mobile application with solely one activity using the Navigation components and Architecture components such as a View Model as I am performing a lot of communication with my data that I stored in room.

In one of my bottom navigation tabs, I have a list that is loaded from all my data in room. So far, I have set up my RecyclerView and my adapter in the `OnCreateView()` (only function used in this fragment) of this list fragment and every thing shows successfully.

The problem is that every time (especially more at first view) the fragment takes a solid 10 seconds to display all the data (which is normal considering there is a lot of it).

My question: Is there a way the adapter and and RecylcerView of this specific fragment could be setup (and load all my data) in the `OnCreate()` of my sole activity? So that when I view the fragment for the first time, everything pops up right away.

Also, how would I go about using `OnPause()` of the list fragment so that when I am on another tab, the list fragment doesn't get destroyed and when we go back on it, it displays right away?

Answer (score -1):

Fetch all data from room inside `onCreate()` method of fragment. The `onDestroyView()` method calls everytime you moves away from the fragment.
 To prevent recreation of views inside fragment store view in a variable.

Example:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment{

    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //fetch data from room
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if(rootView == null)
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```